# Sorting month name in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, query-string

I stored the month name in database as string which looks like

```
Apr-2013
May-2013
...
```

How could i sort the table month wise ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to format the date in order to sort it:

```
select aDate from t
order by str_to_date(aDate,'%b-%Y')
```

This is very inefficient, though. I'd recommend you to update that field and make it a date field or at least two ints: one for the month and one for the year. Then, if you need to get the name of the month you could use the `monthname(date)` function.

Comment: thanks it worked fine for me.I would consider your advise

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  dates
ORDER BY
  STR_TO_DATE(date, '%b-%Y')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fdee8/3/0)